# Pointer arithmetic difference in C# and Visual C++

Tags: c#, c++

If I do this in C#

```cs
int[] arr = new int[] { 0, 1 };

fixed (int* pArr = arr)
{
    int* ppArr = pArr;
    int val = *ppArr + *++ppArr
}
```

I get `val = 1`. This I believe is the correct behavior.

If I do this in C++

```cpp
int* const pArr = new int[2];
pArr[0] = 0;
pArr[1] = 1;

int* ppArr = pArr;
int val = *ppArr + *++ppArr;
```

I get `val = 2`.

Can someone explain why C++ is different? Is there a way to fix it? I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: It is undefined behaviour in C++. You are reading from and modifying `ppArr` between sequence points.

Comment: "Is there a way to fix it?" Don't write convoluted expressions that combine side effects with value computations.

Comment: In this particular case, `ppArr[0] + ppArr[1]` would be a far more readable alternative. Also, `pp` as a prefix on a variable name almost always means pointer-to-pointer (`int **`). If you've got a regular pointer-to-`int`, please don't use `pp` in code meant to be read by others.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks! I had no idea this was undefined in C++. I would mark this as the answer if I could. Also, the duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points explain things quite well. Is it convoluted? Yeah, but the question was more about a difference in behavior than how to write readable code. Good thing to point out though.